# How to find root password hash without root on osx 10.13 High Sierra

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra

I'm going to be using John the Ripper to decrypt the password hash but I don't know where the hash is stored.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You're more likely to find an answer to this on superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

The password hash and salt of any user are located here:

```
/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/<user>.plist
```

You will get a `Permission denied` if you try to access it without sudo.

The only way I know to access it without the sudo password is to reboot in `Single User Mode` (with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)

Once you get there, it's a little tricky to actually get the file and decode it.
You have [a detailed step by step guide here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140703020831/http://www.michaelfairley.co/blog/2014/05/18/how-to-extract-os-x-mavericks-password-hash-for-cracking-with-hashcat/) in the Michael Fairley website (original website no longer available)